# How to set up GPSD for a USB GPS/IRNSS receiver?

Tags: usb, pi-3b+, gps

I am using a Raspberry Pi 3B with a Quectel L89 EVB kit (the receiver). The receiver is connected to the Pi through the USB port. The pi Identifies the connected receiver at ttyUSB0. I'm able to see the NMEA data at

```
cat /dev/ttyUSB0
```

But the commands

```
cgps -s
```

and

```
gpsmon
```

do not show any LAT/LON data output.
How do I setup the GPSD in this case to get the receiver data for further use?

Comment: Hey! I am interested in buying the L89 EVB kit too. Did you figure it out?